# Footer in Master Page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, master-pages, sticky-footer

I have a footer which sticks to the bottom of every page (as i want too), but when I have a lot of text in one of my pages, and need to scroll down, it thinks that the footer is not part of the page, it keeps scroll down till the page text, which cause the footer to go above of the bottom context of the page.

I want the site to scroll down but keep the footer below the page context and over the context.

What should I do?

Here is my master page

**HTML code:**

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="Styles/MasterStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/ShoppingCartSideMenuJavaScript.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/MasterMenuJavaScript.js") %>"></script>

    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="mask">
        </div>
        <div id="ShoppingCartSideMenu">
            <div id="CartMenuTop">
                <div>
                    <img id="menu-close" src="/Images/Icons/X-icon.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="CartHeader">
                    Cart
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 id="SiteTitle">JEWELRY</h1>
            <p id="UnderSiteTitle">EXCLUSIVE SWISS MADE JEWELRY</p>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Home.aspx">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Shop.aspx">SHOP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="About.aspx">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="TermsAndConditions.aspx">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact.aspx">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li id="seperator">|
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div id="CartImage">
                            <a id="ShoppingCartBtn">
                                <img class="ShoppingCart" src="/Images/Icons/Shopping_cart.png" />
                                <label id="CountCartItems">0</label>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="FooterWrapper">
                <div id="FooterDiv1">
                    &copy; 2016 JEWELRY - Created by nirh1989
                </div>
                <div id="FooterDiv2">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img id="FooterFacebook" class="Icons" alt="Facebook" src="/Images/Icons/facebook-logo.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img id="FooterTwitter" class="Icons" alt="Twitter" src="/Images/Icons/twitter-logo.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img id="FooterInstagram" class="Icons" alt="Instagram" src="/Images/Icons/instagram-logo.png" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS code:**

```
body {
}

form {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#SiteTitle {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

#UnderSiteTitle {
    font-family: raleway;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

#menu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
    font-family: arial;
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 37px;
}

#menu ul li a, a:visited, a:active {
    transition: 2s;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
    transition: 0.25s;
    color: gray;
}

#menu ul li .active {
    transition: 0s;
    color: gray;
    }


#seperator {
    color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: -11px
}

#CartImage {
    position: relative;
}

.ShoppingCart {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer
}

#ShoppingCartBtn {
        cursor: pointer;
}

#CountCartItems {
    position: relative;
    right: 24px;
    bottom: 21px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mask {
    background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.8);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 250;
}

#ShoppingCartSideMenu {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 350px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: -350px;
    z-index: 350;
}

#CartMenuTop {
    background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#CartHeader {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: arial;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 150px;
}

#menu-close {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

.FooterWrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#FooterDiv1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
    color: #595959;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#FooterDiv2 {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 17px;
}

.Icons {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

Also, attach image for example of my problem [image]

Comment: have you tried placing the footer outside of the form tag?

Comment: Your ContentPlaceHolder is probably inheriting a max height style.  Use the element picker in your browser's dev tools to highlight that div.  Then look through the applied styles to see if it's inheriting a max height style.

Comment: i tried to put the footer outside of the form tag, still same result

Comment: i checked with the dev tool, it seems like the `.wrapper` is from the top till the menu, even that all the content is inside it

Comment: Add some bottom padding to the wrapper class?

Comment: tried... nothing... according to the browser dev tool, look like the `wrapper` ends in the `menu`, and not in the `asp:ContentPlaceHolder `, which is weird, and i think maybe the problem is there... but do not know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, change your footer to position: absolute, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0. 
Then add this to your body tag:

```
body{
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 15rem;
}
```

Comment: Or position: fixed, like in your example. My bad.

Comment: it is already fixed, with bottom:0, just added the `padding-bottom` but it did not solved the problem... any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add padding-bottom to the body tag? Try applying more padding.

Comment: I thought that was working, but apparently it is not, i need the footer to go automatically down when there is contact, but that is not what happening, i think because for some reason the body think it end with the menu and not with the actual page context... so what can i do?

Comment: i had `float:left` in another css file of another page, and that cause the problem. i removed it of course and now it's ok. thank you everyone.